# How to read fast with Python from MS SQL

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

How to fast search specific data in MS SQL with Python if you have three dependent variables and you have 10 million data? If prepare use pyodbc library or any else?

Comment: You'd need to give more information showing your exact query, and your table schema. Are these variables range lookups or singleton/equality lookups? Are they always searched together, always separately, or varying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from the fact that 10 million rows for a table in a RDBMS is not a huge number, I personally used [TurboODBC](https://turbodbc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) with MSSQL to migrate a table with ~2 billion rows. I was very satisfied.

You should carefully review and optimize your query/schema (adding indexes, exploiting them, etc.) regardless of the technology you will use to run it. Most likely the database query execution will be the bottleneck of your process (assuming that you will not process this data in python).

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations and your advice. I will use TurboODBC and see if is database query execution will be the bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

Using a columnstore index is appropriate for high volume of data/rows in a table (many millions at least). If your criterias for the WHERE cluse of the SELECT are the 3 variables, create such index with those three columns. As an hypothetical exemple :

```
CREATE COLUMNSTORE INDEX XC_MyTable ON MyTable (Col1, Col2, Col3);
```